# Display a stream of bitmaps at 60fps smoothly on Android 4.x

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview, frame-rate

(This is due to the limitations of the server software I will be using, if I could change it, I would).

I am receiving a sequence of 720x480 JPEG files (about 6kb in size), over a socket. I have benchmarked the network, and have found that I am capable of receiving those JPEGs smoothly, at 60FPS.

My current drawing operation is on a Nexus 10 display of 2560x1600, and here's my decoding method, once I have received the byte array from the socket:

```
public static void decode(byte[] tmp, Long time) {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tmp, 0, tmp.length, options);
        Bitmap background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap
                (bitmap, MainActivity.screenwidth, MainActivity.screenheight, false);
        background.setHasAlpha(false);
            Canvas canvas = MainActivity.surface.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, new Paint());
            MainActivity.surface.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am clearing the canvas from a SurfaceView, and then drawing the Bitmap to the SurfaceView. My issue is that it is very, very, slow.

Some tests based on adding System.currentTimeMillis() before and after the lock operation result in approximately a 30ms difference between getting the canvas, drawing the bitmap, and then pushing the canvas back. The displayed SurfaceView is *very* laggy, sometimes it jumps back and forth, and the frame rate is terrible.

Is there a referred method for drawing like this? Again, I can't modify what I'm getting from the server, but I'd like the bitmaps to be displayed at 60FPS when possible.

(I've tried setting the contents of an ImageView, and am receiving similar results). I have no other code in the SurfaceView that could impact this. I have set the holder to the RGBA_8888 format:

```
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Is it possible to convert this stream of Bitmaps into a VideoView? Would that be faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you run into performance questions, use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to figure out exactly where your problem lies. Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` is like attempting to trim a steak with a hammer.

The #1 thing her is to **get the bitmap decoding off the main application thread**. Do that in a background thread. Your main application thread should *just* be drawing the bitmaps, pulling them off of a queue populated by that background thread. Android has the main application thread set to render on a 60fps basis as of Android 4.1 (a.k.a., "Project Butter"), so as long as you can draw your `Bitmap` in a couple of milliseconds, and assuming that your network and decoding can keep your queue current, you should get 60fps results.

Also, **always use `inBitmap`** with `BitmapFactory.Options` on Android 3.0+ when you have images of consistent size, as part of your problem will be GC stealing CPU time. Work off a pool of `Bitmap` objects that you rotate through, so that you generate less garbage and do not fragment your heap so much.

I suspect that you are better served letting Android scale the image for you in an `ImageView` (or just by drawing to a `View` canvas) than you are in having `BitmapFactory` scale the image, as Android can take advantage of hardware graphics acceleration for rendering, which `BitmapFactory` cannot. Again, Traceview is your friend here.

With regards to:

> and have found that I am capable of receiving those JPEGs smoothly, at 60FPS.

that will only be true sometimes. Mobile devices tend to be mobile. Assuming that by "6kb" you mean 6KB (six kilobytes), you are assuming a ~3Mbps (three megabits per second) connection, and that's far from certain.

With regards to:

> Is it possible to convert this stream of Bitmaps into a VideoView?

`VideoView` is a widget that plays videos, and you do not have a video.

Push come to shove, you might need to drop down to the NDK and do this in native code, though I would hope not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that call is from my network thread. The bitmap decoding is done outside of the UI thread.

However, if I do use your imageview suggestion, how would I update the ImageView from another thread?

As for the networking, this is over a 54Mb/s LAN, so I'm certain I shouldn't need to worry about that. This will be over wifi, and isn't intended for general use.

Again, thanks for the help, I'll see how I can set the ImageView from a separate thread.

Comment: @user2592851: You wouldn't. What I would be trying is having the decoding thread generate `Bitmap` objects and put them on a `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Your custom `View` (or perhaps a subclass of `ImageView`) would `poll()` to grab a `Bitmap` in its `onDraw()` method, waiting perhaps a couple of milliseconds if needed, then render it. This puts the rendering on the main application thread, independent of your decoding. Basically, you have a pipeline: network thread transfers byte arrays to a queue for the decoding thread, which transfers `Bitmaps` to a queue for rendering.

Comment: @user2592851: "This will be over wifi" -- you need to attend more conferences and experience the joys of large-group WiFi networks. :-)

Comment: so I would put a `public static LinkedBlockingQueue queue` in the main thread, and then on the network/decode thread, I call put(bitmap). I'm not overly familiar with the drawing process, do I manually call onDraw() from my method, or is it called automatically?

Again, thanks for the help.

As for inBitmap, I assume that I would set the previous bitmap as that?

Comment: @user2592851: You definitely do not call `onDraw()` directly. I did screw up part of my analysis, though -- something has to trigger the rendering. Off the cuff, since you're targeting a Nexus 10, I'd probably try `Choreographer` and `postFrameCallback()` and do the check-the-queue-for-a-`Bitmap` work in that `Runnable`. If there's a `Bitmap`, put it on the `ImageView` (or `invalidate()` your `View` if you're going with a custom `View`). And, whether or not you got a `Bitmap`, call `postFrameCallback()` to schedule yourself for the next frame. `Choreographer` is what manages the 60fps part.

Comment: @ylin: "As for inBitmap, I assume that I would set the previous bitmap as that?" -- well, since the queues are working asynchronously from the rendering, you will probably need a small pool of `Bitmap` objects. At decoding time, pull a `Bitmap` out of the pool and use it with `inBitmap`. When you render a frame, the *previous* `Bitmap` can be returned to the pool for reuse.

Comment: @ylin: My apologies for not having a complete solution for this queueing concept. I'm brainstorming how I'd be approaching the problem, given that I have never needed to do anything exactly like this before.

Comment: I'd prefer you not to do all the work for me, but thanks for fleshing this out. I'm surprised that this isn't used quite often (especially considering the other drawBitmap() speed issues on this site). However, I'm still confused about the pooling. I would need to discard older images, but forgive my synchronous syncing, but would reusing a bitmap cause the timeline to jump back and forth?

Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for spamming this thread, but I have created a `List<Bitmap>` pool of Bitmaps, and a `LinkedBlockingQueue<Bitmap>` for the UI thread. I have then turned my decoding into a separate `Runnable`, and it checks for a bitmap in the pool (and uses inBitmap if there is), adds the Bitmap to the queue, and then removes the first Bitmap from the pool. That's good and all, but I couldn't find much documentation about Choreographer. Would I have to make a Looper in my main activity, and get the choreographer for that? Or could I make a Timer that checks every 8 milliseconds or so?

Comment: @ylin: The main application thread already has a `Looper`. Just make sure you are working with `Choreographer` on the main application. `Timer` gives you a background thread, and if you thought your original results sucked, `Timer` would make them suck worse.

Comment: Again, sorry about my lack of knowledge (and the lack of documentation), but after I've gotten the `Choreographer` for the main activity with `Choreographer.getInstance()`, what would I do? Would I implement a `Choreographer class` that overrides the `postFrameCallback()`? Would I make the main activity implement `Choreographer.Callback`? Thanks.

Comment: @ylin: "what would I do?" -- you would call `postFrameCallback()` to register a `FrameCallback` to be called at the beginning of the next frame. That `FrameCallback` can see if there is a `Bitmap` ready. If there is, use it. Whether there is or is not, call `postFrameCallback()` to schedule yourself to run again at the start of the next frame. Where you choose to implement `FrameCallback` is up to you.

Comment: I guess my question is, what do I put in the ImageDecoder thread? I assume I would just `MainActivity.choreographer.postFrameCallback()`, but what would the callback be? I see it (`new Choreographer.FrameCallback()`) implementing a method `doFrame()`, so in that `doFrame()`, would I check for an existing bitmap in the queue (if there is a new one), and push it:

    `MainActivity.mImageView.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.queue.poll());`

 Thanks.

Comment: Actually, thanks! I've gotten the `postFrameCallback()` working, and it *definitely* is a lot faster than my previous drawing, even without the pooling. Final question before I work on the pool: What does the `SkImageDecoder: Cannot reuse bitmap with sampleSize != 1` mean? Am I running out of pooled objects? Thanks.

Comment: @ylin: I do not recognize that error message. If I had to guess, perhaps you are still calling `createScaledBitmap()`, and perhaps that does not work with `inBitmap`.

Comment: I have completely removed that line from my code, but thanks! Even without the pooling, this is *much* faster already. Do you think making the bitmap mutable would help?

Edit: nope. I'll be asking another question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: one last thing: Is there a benefit for pooling inBitmap? Why would I use that versus just using the first Bitmap received?

Comment: @ylin: Because that `Bitmap` may be in use. You are in a multi-thread situation. You need to make sure that a `Bitmap` is only being used by one thread at a time. And you need to make sure that you do not reuse a `Bitmap` via `inBitmap` until you are done with it (i.e., your code on the main application thread has moved along to another `Bitmap` and is no longer dependent upon your current one).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've gotten the pooling implemented, and it definitely is much smoother than before.